# proper installation sequence of Aptana, node.js, ruby, SASS

Tags: node.js, ruby, git, aptana

My wife of 13 years, Dreamweaver, was killed by the Windows 10 Fall upgrade.
In recovery, I'm hooking up with Aptana.

So, I must uninstall and re-install WampStack,
download Aptana,
JDK,
Node.js,
Ruby,
and Git.

In your experience, is there a proper sequence by which I should download and install these components?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the document I overlooked.
https://github.com/aptana/studio3/wiki/Getting-Started